# Renewing a SSL certificate with GoDaddy

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, security-certificate

GoDaddy sells SSL certificates for $12 per year (the most basic one). I have bought one of those last year, and now is the time to renew. However they are now asking for $50 for the renewal (the $12 is apparently a discount).

Is there a way to get the $12 price for a renewal. Is it going to work if I buy a new certificate at $12, and use the same host as the one I had before, or are they going to prevent me from doing that?

Comment: Voting to close. This is between you and GoDaddy. Pricing questions are generally out of place here, anyway.

Comment: @Su' Leaving aside the price, is there a technical difference between renewing a certificate and buying a new one?

Comment: Flavien: Could you provide a direct link to this $12 offer? Paul: *Technically* no, but this isn't really a technical question; it's about whether there's a "new customer" restriction on a discount. But I'll humor it below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a link to whatever offer you're referring to, and I can't find that $12 dollar cost anywhere on GoDaddy's site via normal navigation, so there's an obvious speculative element here.
I was able to hunt down [this price comparison page](http://www.godaddy.com/compare/gdcompare2_ssl.aspx?isc=sslj049&ef_id=7nBOoGrcxhYAAApT:20120817183546:s) via Google, which does list a $12.99/yr offer.

If you scroll past the comparison table, then keep going further past "Those who use" and "About our SSLs", you'll see a very small "Click here for product disclaimers and legal policies." link. And from there:

> ‡ Annual discounts available on NEW purchases only.

(In case the page I link to isn't the exact one you saw, there's probably a similar link somewhere on your page so look anyway.)
That double dagger symbol refers back to the drop-down where you'd select how many years for which you want to purchase the certificate, and seemingly no other references to the price, if you want to yell at customer service and try to wedge a discount out of them or something.

But short version: No. You're stuck paying full price.

[A bit later]
Interesting. Now that I've been to the offer page, I see this *constantly*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try calling them, and if they still want me to pay the full price I'll go to a competitor that sells them around $14.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the offer discounts to new customers, so they will probably be able to tell if you use the same account that you are an existing customer and won't be entitled for one of their promotions.

I would call them, they may be able to cut you a deal over the phone, you never know.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that big brand like this are always offer discount price for first time and then start charging big for renewal. I found many people crying by considering renewal rate.

What i recommend is: Just buy new SSL from Authorized resellers like ClickSSL, as renewal price and offer price by such resellers are always lower as compare to big brand. Here you can get same SSL as huge discounted price and renewal rate is also same.

Just search in Google and buy from authorized SSL certificate provider.